# Can't constrain generic types to be equivalent in Swift 5

Tags: swift, generics, types

Why doesn't Swift allow this generic function:

I'm trying to express a generic function that will take two "number" types, and compare them, could be Ints, Floats, Doubles etc...

Why does Swift say `Same-type requirement makes generic parameters 'T' and 'U' equivalent`, what's wrong with that?

```
func isSameNumber <T, U> (lhs: T, rhs: U) where T: Numeric, U:Numeric, T == U {
    if lhs == rhs {
        print("true")
    }
    else{
        print("false")
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you use `lhs == rhs ? "true" : "false"` directly where you want to call this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `T == U`, then you only have a single generic type, so don't declare 2 generic types. You simply need to constraint both input arguments to the same generic type, `T`.

```
func isSameNumber<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) where T: Numeric {
    if lhs == rhs {
        print("true")
    }
    else{
        print("false")
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting that this is effectively the same thing... `func anyCommonElements <T, U> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> [U.Element] where T: Sequence, U: Sequence, T.Element: Equatable, T.Element == U.Element` but it doesn't complain, what do you think @Dávid Pásztor

Comment: @Woodstock well, that's not the same thing, really. You can have 2 different sequences, whose elements are of the same type, so `T` and `U` are not equivalent in that sequence example. Here's a concrete example: `T` being `Set<Int>` and `U` being `Array<Int>`.

Comment: Another good example is an array of characters and a string

Comment: @Woodstock Btw there is already a native sequence method exactly for this purpose [elementsEqual](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2854213-elementsequal)